# find an embedding such as F from each numerable and countable set to $Q$

Tags: first-order-logic

Imagine we have a vocabulary called $V$ and we have two $V-structures$ such as $M$ and $N$.
An embedding is a function from $U_M$ to $U_N$ which preserves the interpretation of $V-formulas$.
Now i want to find a embedding from each numerable and countable set to $Q$.
Note : $Q$ is the set of rational numbers.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question is a little bit... underdetermined. Are there any restrictions or requirements on $V$? The predicates, function symbols and constants of $V$ are familiar things (such as $<, +, 0, ...$)? or are they just whatever you get by transporting those relations etc on $U_M$ to $\Bbb Q$ via a bijection?

Comment: @BrianO no sir there is no other information in the question . but i know my teacher at university and if he didn't say anything else in the question, it means that this is all we got. and also about bijection, remember that bijection is for when we want to prove that they have the same size. but i just want to prove that a numerable and countable set's size is less than or equal size to Q.

Comment: OK, I believe you :) To show that $\Bbb Q$ is countably infinite, it's enough to show that there's a bijection $\Bbb Q \to \Bbb N$, or equivalently, that there are injections from each to the other. As we can assume $\Bbb N\subseteq \Bbb Q$, it's enough to give an injection $\Bbb Q \to \Bbb N$ — or, equivalently, a surjection $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N \to \Bbb Q$. The result about embeddings then follows simply by using the bijection to "transfer" the structure from $(M, ...)$ to $(\Bbb Q, ...)$.

Comment: @BrianO you mean that if i prove that Q is countable and infinite , then i can conclude that every countable and numerable set's size is less than or equal to Q ? i say this because the question doesn't force us to provide an embedding it just wants us to prove that an embedding exists.

Comment: Yes. One point about terminology, though: Usually (in English) we say that a set is *countable* if it's either finite or bijectable with $\Bbb N$; *countably infinite*, or *denumerably infinite*, if it's countable and infinite (thus, bijectable with $\Bbb N$). Clearly, two sets that are countably infinite are of the same size, and a countable set is of size less-equal $\Bbb N$. Once you show that $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Q$ are of the same size (bijectable), you'll know that the size of every countable set is $\le$ the size of $\Bbb Q$, and every countably infinite set has the same size as $\Bbb Q$.